# Mean Value Theorem Example

Tags: calculus

Find the number $c$ guaranteed by the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals for $f(x) =10−x$ on the interval $[2,6]$.

I tried just finding the slope and then setting that equal to the derivative of my $fx$ but I'm not getting the right answer. This should be simple but it's not.

I got $-1$ as an answer but its $4$.

Comment: Why did I get 3 down votes for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on a phone, I'll clean up as soon as I can.

The MVT for integral says there is a $c$ between $a$ and $b$ such that
$$\int_a^b f(x)\ dx = (b-a)f(c)$$
First compute the integral, then find the value of $c$ wihich satisfy the MVT.
$$\int_2^6 (10-x)\ dx = (6-2)(10-c)$$
$$24=4(10-c)$$
$$c=4$$

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. THanks

Answer (score 0):

So to find $c\in[2,6]$ that satisfies
$$\begin{align*}
\int_2^6f(x)\ dx &= f(c)(6-2)\\
\int_2^6(10-x)\ dx&= (10-c) (6-2)\\
\end{align*}$$

Solve for $c$.

Comment: Why is it not 1/b-a times the integral from 2 to 6 (10 -x) dx? And why is it equal to (10-c)(6-2). What is the mean value theorem? Can you show me a formula?

Comment: Nevermind the other guy showed me the formula

Comment: Thanks for the help tho